# tweepy: finding the original author of a retweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm kind of a python newb and stuck with tweepy here.

What I'm trying to do is bring in a bunch of user and tweet objects into a neo4j database with tweet and retweet relationships.  My problem is in determining if a given status object is a retweet and if so the screen_name and id_str of the original author.

I can see the data if I print out tweet.retweets but I can't figure out how to get to it.  tweepy's docs mention something about object models and for more information check out ModelsReference but google isn't helping me much here.

any help would be great, even just pointing me in the right direction.  Thanks

Sample code

```
tweets=api.get_timeling(1234556)
twitter_user=api.get_user(123456)
for tweet in tweets:
    neo4j_create_tweet_node(tweet)
    if tweet.user.id == twitter_user.id:
        create_tweet_relationship(twitter_user,tweet)
    elif tweet.user.id != twitter_user.id:
        create_retweet_relationship(twitter_user,tweet)
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose tweet is a retweet, 
originalAuthorID = tweet.retweeted_status.user.id_str;

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets):

> Retweets can be distinguished from typical Tweets by the existence of a `retweeted_status` attribute. This attribute contains a representation of the original Tweet that was retweeted. Note that retweets of retweets do not show representations of the intermediary retweet, but only the original tweet.

I would use `hasattr()` to look for the presence of the `retweeted_status` atttibute in each Tweetpy tweet object.

The following code (where `create_tweet_relationship()` and `create_retweet_relationship()` are functions you have defined as in your example) seems like it should would work:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    if hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status'):
         create_tweet_relationship(tweet.retweeted_status.author, tweet)
    else:
         create_retweet_relationship(tweet.author, tweet)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tweet is a retweet of another, the original retweeted status is included in the JSON object in the field "retweeted_status". You'd get the user information there under the "user" field.